# Saving checked values from checkedlistbox to an array and storing it to mysql database

Tags: vb.net

I have already stored the checked values on an array, but when only 1 item is checked and I try to save it, I get an error: index was outside the bounds of the array, while checking 2 or more values will have no errors. Please help.

```
Dim count as Integer
Dim ListedItems As New ArrayList()
for count = 0 To (CLB1.Items.Count - 1)
    ListItems.Add(CLB1.GetItemText(CLB1.CheckedItems(count)).ToString)
    query("Insert Into accnts (accnts.IDNo, accnts.PayName) Values ('" & IDTB.Text &"','" & ListItems(count) & "')
    MsgBox("Record Saved",MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly)
Next
```

Comment: Post code. Show what you've tried so far. Explain why it didn't work.

Comment: Thank you and I Have added my code. What happens when I press the button, I got to check desired checkboxes from CheckedListBox, and I got to store it to an array named ListedItems. But, when I only check 1 checkedbox and pass that 1 value to the array, I get the error Index was outside of bounds of the array. While checking 2 values gives me no error and still passes the selected value to my database. How do I get rid of that error?

Comment: `CLB1.CheckedItems(count))` count goes from 0 to number of _total_ checkbox items - 1. If not all of the items are selected, you'll end up indexing an array of N elements with an index that becomes >= N, causing an "index out of bounds" error.

Answer (score 0):

Try taversing only the checked item and not all the items in checkbox list like:

```
For Each indexChecked In CLB1.CheckedIndices 
    ListItems.Add(CLB1.Items(indexChecked).ToString)
    query("Insert Into accnts (accnts.IDNo, accnts.PayName) Values ('" & IDTB.Text &"','" & ListItems(ListItems.Count-1) & "')
    MsgBox("Record Saved",MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly)
Next
```

By the way your query is susceptible to sql injection try using parameters to prevent one link [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue.aspx)